# Enable SSL on test node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, angularjs

I'm trying to adapt the [node server included with the angular-seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/scripts/web-server.js) to serve SSL. Based on this [example](http://book.mixu.net/ch10.html) where they have:

```
// HTTPS
var https = require('https');
// read in the private key and certificate
var pk = fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem');
var pc = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.pem');
var opts = { key: pk, cert: pc };
// create the secure server
var serv = https.createServer(opts, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  res.end();
});
// listen on port 443
serv.listen(443, '0.0.0.0');
```

I tried the following, which appears to run (no errors are logged), however when I navigate to `https://localhost:8000/home` I get "This webpage is not available"  `http://localhost:8000/home`- non SSL - worked before I hacked the node server. How can I get this to work as SSL?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    https = require('https'),
    events = require('events');

// read in the private key and certificate
var pk = fs.readFileSync('./scripts/privatekey.pem');
var pc = fs.readFileSync('./scripts/certificate.pem');
var opts = { key: pk, cert: pc };

var DEFAULT_PORT = 8000;

function main(argv) {  
  // create the secure server
  new HttpServer({ key: pk, cert: pc,
    'GET': createServlet(StaticServlet),
    'HEAD': createServlet(StaticServlet)
  }).start(Number(argv[2]) || DEFAULT_PORT);
}
[... balance of script omitted ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node server code defines

```
function HttpServer(handlers) {
  this.handlers = handlers;
  this.server = http.createServer(this.handleRequest_.bind(this));
}
```

which it then goes on to extend as for example:

```
HttpServer.prototype.start = function(port) {
  this.port = port;
  this.server.listen(port);
  util.puts('Http Server running at http://localhost:' + port + '/');
};
```

Based on a further reading of the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html) it's this fragement: `http.createServer(this.handleRequest_.bind(this))` that would have to become `https.createServer(this.handleRequest_.bind(this))` -- I'm still not sure where / how to pass the certificate keys into the process.

Given that an equivalent express ssl server would be easier to figure out, I think I'll just switch.  *(The following is untested.  I'll update as needed once I've tested.)*

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Create an HTTP service.
// http.createServer(app).listen(80);

// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```